# CLI0145E db2_fetch_array

Tags: php, db2

i'm working with DB2 in php and i'm getting the following error while executing

```
@$row = db2_fetch_array( $res );
[IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0145E Fetch type out of range. SQLSTATE=HY106 SQLCODE=-99999
```

I found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.db2-fetch-row.php#72501) a possible explanation, but it doesn't make sense for me because i'm not specifying the row number.

Does anybody can give some explanations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have misunderstood the suggestion contained in the [page that you referenced](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.db2-fetch-row.php#72501).  It is not referring to the `db2_fetch_array()` function, but to the `db2_connect()` function.  To set the cursor option to `DB2_SCROLLABLE`, pass this constant into the fourth parameter of the database connection function:

```
db2_connect('database', 'username', 'password', DB2_SCROLLABLE);
```

If this is not the correct solution, maybe it is displaying that error because the result contains 0 rows?  It is always a good idea to check to make sure at least one row was returned before calling `db2_fetch_array()` (or a related function):

```
if (db2_num_rows($res) > 0){
  @$row = db2_fetch_array( $res );
}
```